# How to use css modules with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, css-modules

According to a [tweet](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/953651118147604480) by Dan Abramov, CSS modules support is there in create-react-app (CRA). One just needs to give extension of `module.css` to his stylesheets to enable the feature, but this is not working with me. I am having version 1.1.4 of `react-scripts`. How can I enable css modules with CRA? Thanks

Comment: It's only available on cra v2. See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/2285

Comment: did you manga to figure out how to get your app to display correctly on firebase?  yarn upgrade react-scripts@latest yielded the same results after i uploaded the new build.

Comment: almost every answer here: "no problem, lets get rid of cra by ejecting it first". Seriously?

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You do not need to eject.

Create React App supports CSS Modules right out of the box as of version 2.

Upgrade to the [latest (`react-scripts@latest`)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-react-app?activeTab=versions) version.

If you use yarn:

```sh
yarn upgrade react-scripts@latest
```

If you use npm:

```sh
npm install --save react-scripts@latest
```

Then you just have to create a file with the extension `.module.css`

For example:

```css
.myStyle {
  color: #fff
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```jsx
import React from 'react'
import styles from './mycssmodule.module.css'

export default () => <div className={styles.myStyle}>We are styled!</div>
```

Comment: I'm using react-scripts@1.1.5 and it doesn't work. Am i using the good version of react-scripts ?

Comment: @Emidomh next major version will start with 2. Run the command I wrote in the answer if you would like to upgrade. You can see the versions [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scripts?activeTab=versions)

Answer (score 11):

To enable CSS module in to your app, you don't need to eject create-react-app. You can follow these simple steps described in [this link](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet) to use CSS module in your project.

But in case if you ejected your create-react-app, then you must find file named

> "webpack.config.js"

open this file and find this {test:cssRegex....etc} in line no. 391 and replace to this changes:

```
            {
              test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
            }),
            },
```

Open .js file and import statement like this

```
import cssStyleClassName from './MyApp.css';
```

Then this import statement allow you to do following changes in component tags like this

```
<div className={cssStyleClassName.styleName}></div>
```

styleName is what you defined in your MyAppStyle.css file

```
.styleName{
your properties here...
}
```

After eject your app, you must restart your local server, sometime changes don't get reflect.

**Note** In earlier version there were two generated file for production and dev separately. Now in current version one file named "webpack.config.js" file for which you need to concerned for changes. Thank you.

Comment: New to react here. I think I ejected my create-react-app. I don't have a webpack.config.js file only webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js inside config folder. Do I make webpack.config.js file in the root and add what code?

Comment: this solution will not work with react-scripts version larger than 2, you should use this solution :
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/

Answer (score 2):

i am using `3.4.1` version of the `react-scripts` so here is my approach

1. run the command :`npm run eject`
   2.Then you will get  a config file , in that open `webpack.config.js`
2. And search `test: cssRegex` or just search `cssRegex`
3. now you will see something like this:

```
test: cssRegex,
              exclude: cssModuleRegex,
              use: getStyleLoaders({
                importLoaders: 1,
                sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
              }),
```

now after `importLoaders:1,` add `modules:true,` and just `save` the file.
5.Now you can restart the server using `npm start` and you will see your styles applied.
(if you already know them how to use)

here  when I used   `[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]`
because I got an error that

```
 - options has an unknown property 'localIdentName'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
```

so I  removed it and I just used `modules:true`
and it worked for me.

Comment: I tried so hard to find this :(
It works and Thank you. :)

Comment: new update, it even works without these settings

Answer (score 2):

1. Run the command `npm run eject`
2. Open the `webpack.config.js` file.
3. Find `test: cssRegex` section and edit it like following:

```
{
  test: cssRegex,
  exclude: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
      : isEnvDevelopment,
    modules: {
      // mode: 'icss',
      getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
    },
  }),
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to eject create-react-app and then in config files  for webpack you add these 2 lines
[image]

And to use it load css to Component you wan't (i keed component and it's css in same folder)

```
import classes from './SomeComponentStyle.css';
```

...

```
<div className={classes.RedDiv}>
```

inside SomeComponentStyle.css

```
.RedDiv {
  /* styles for red div */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using version 1.1.4 , so CSS Modules doesn't work by default ... above version 2.0, it works default by changing the css file name to name.module.css.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your `react-scripts` version (*you can check the version in `package.json` file*):

**For `react-scripts` version before `2.0.0`:**

1. if you are using git in your project you should commit your changes and push them.
2. do `npm run eject`
3. edit your webpack config files `dev` and `prod` with these changes:
   [image: webpack config changes]
4. if you are running your app, stop it and rerun it, hence you will find your changes and can then use CSS modules.

---

**Starting with `react-scripts` version `2.0.0`:**

You can follow
"[Adding a CSS Modules Stylesheet](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/)" from the official `create-react-app` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

### Heading ##i use react-script version 3.4.3 (latest version). you simply follow the below given steps.

run the command :npm run eject

Then you will get a config file , in that open webpack.config.js

And search test: cssRegex or just search cssRegex
now you will see something like this:

test: cssRegex,

```
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          }),
```

now after importLoaders:1, add modules:true, and just save the file.

Now you can restart the server using npm start and you will see your styles applied.

Open .js file and import statement like this

```
import cssStyleClassName from './MyAppStyle.css';
```

please do not forget to add **.css** extension to the styling file, at the time of import.

Then this import statement allow you to do following changes in component tags like this

`<div className={cssStyleClassName.styleName}></div>`

`styleName` is what you defined in your `MyAppStyle.css` file

```
.styleName{
your properties here...
}
```

Comment: Its not wise to eject just to use css modules, you will lose all the updating you get from using create react app, and will need to manage all the depndencies yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
In webpack.config.js file find this keyword 'css-loader'.
You will find below code in line number 82 for react version-16.13
{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: cssOptions,      
}

Replace above object with 

{
   loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
   options: {
      modules: {
        mode: "local",
        localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64:5]"
      },
      import: true,
      importLoaders: true
    }     
}

Start the server again by npm start(If changes are not reflected)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fresh library called [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles) package.

It's introducing a more declarative way of applying styles. You need to wrap your code with `<PatchStyles classNames={style}>` where `style` is the default import from the style module. See the example of usage in [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

With React-17.0.2, Run below script

> npm run eject

Go to file

> webpack.config.js

Search for

> cssRegex

Add module object as below

```
          test: cssRegex,
          exclude: cssModuleRegex,
          use: getStyleLoaders({
            importLoaders: 1,
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction
              ? shouldUseSourceMap
              : isEnvDevelopment,
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]"
              }
          })
```

Then your css file will work with name Eg. header.css