# CSS modules not styling my app when deployed to Firebase. Create React App

Tags: css, reactjs, create-react-app, firebase-hosting, react-css-modules

I changed the webpack.config.dev.js and webpack.config.prod.js both in the config folder and in node_modules/react-scripts/config folder to allow for CSS modules like this:

```
test: /\.css$/,
loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
  Object.assign(
    {
      fallback: require.resolve('style-loader'),
      use: [
        {
          loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
          options: {
            importLoaders: 1,
                        modules: true,
                        localIdentName: '[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]'
```

When I run my app in dev mode with `npm start` it works just fine and the CSS modules apply correctly.

However, when I `build` my app and deploy it to Firebase the CSS styling disappears.

Is this a common issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: Please read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51128749/5007662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you upgrade to react-scripts version 2 you don't need to eject in order to make this work. The build will automatically work with css modules. I would recommend upgrading your react-scripts to `v2` using `yarn upgrade react-scripts@latest`

Then rerun `yarn build` and see if the deploy works properly. You won't need to modify your webpack configuration for this.